# solr join use case (not in instead of in)

Tags: solr

Solr has implemented from version 4 the !join query.

I'd like to know if the following  case is possible. 
For example, we have documents of the following form: 
   doc1: 
            field1:123 
            field2:A 
            field3:456 
   doc2: 
           field1:123
           field2:B
           field3:789
    doc3:
           field1:23456
           field2:A
           field3:264

We need to retrieve all the documents that the field field2 equals to
B and no other document with the same field field1 value containing
the field field2 with value A.

In SQL this can be done with the operation "not in": 
select * from doc
where field2 = 'B' and field1 not in (select field1 from doc where
field2 = 'A')

The join operator is the equivalent of the SQL in operator.

Can we use the solr join or another function to implements our needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nested query](https://lucidworks.com/blog/nested-queries-in-solr/) for this purposes. Here's same question and answer for it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191274/4304116

Here is query for your example:

```
q=-_query_:"{!join from=doc_id to=id}field2:'A'"
```

It will return all docs that not with "A" value for field2.

Also you can just add to q another condition(if you need only "B" value):

```
q={!join from=doc_id to=id}field2:'B'"
```

It will return all docs with 'B' value for field2.

Comment: add an example and use the link as more information on the subject.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl added examples for cases that crls123 asked.