# Solr join "not in" subselect

Tags: solr

In the Solr join documentation [Solr Join](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) they say that:

```
/solr/collection1/select ? fl=xxx,yyy & q={!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

How do I write in Solr (see the NOT):

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id NOT IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

Lets consider the following example:
People Records:

```
1. name='a', id=1, teacherId=4
2. name='b', id=2, teacherId=4
3. name='c', id=3, teacherId=1
4. name='d', id=4, isTeacher='true'
```

Now I want to select all students which their teacherId points to non teacher ID (record #3).
In SQL:

```
select * from people where teacherId not in (select id where isTeacher='true').
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855830/how-to-do-not-in-query-in-solr

Comment: This doesn't help me since I need to collect the IDs (select id from Y) by another Solr query @highland

Comment: Well, that's what a fq= does, so what kind of query are we talking about here?

Comment: fq adds an additional filter with AND to the main query. I want to fetch all green objects which their owner field isn't in another solr query. @fiskfisk

Comment: @AvnerLevy Shouldn't that be the same as a negative query with the same as you'd put in the WHERE field of the inner query? Do you have a few rows showing the exact issue? (I see where you're going, but I fail to see how the negative query would fail)

Comment: @fiskfisk In my example I have two type of documents. X and X_mirror, where for each X document I create a X_mirror mirror document. Then part of the X documents are removed and I want to find all the X_mirror objects which are redundant (since their original X document was removed).

Comment: @AvnerLevy Ah, thanks for the explanation! I'm not sure if that's possible at the moment, there's been a few unanswered questions regarding the same issue. If there was some way to get a dynamic lookup for the docfreq with the value from another field in the document (instead of a static value), that would be a solution .. but there doesn't seem to be a way at the moment. You might want to try the mailing list for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try put "-" outside of the whole join filter, like below:

/solr/collection1/select ? fl=xxx,yyy & q=-({!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv)

Answer (score 6):

I'm faced with this problem too and that's how I resolved it:

```
q=-_query_:"{!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv"
```

You can add this [nested query](https://lucidworks.com/blog/nested-queries-in-solr/) to `fq` too.

Hope that helps!)

Comment: This solution works also when the query contains parenthesis. You also have to escape double quotes (replace " with \") if they appear in the query

Comment: This is better than using the join in the Q param in my oppinion, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id NOT IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz != "vvv")
```

where `NOT IN` becomes `IN` and `zzz = "vvv"` becomes `zzz != "vvv"`, then negating the actual query should work.

```
/solr/collection1/select ? fl=xxx,yyy & q={!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}-zzz:vvv
```

Note the `-zzz:vvv`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please see comment about the mirror example. This answer doesn't answer this scenario.