# Solr facet on subset of documents

Tags: solr, facet

I have Solr documents that can have 3 possible states (`state_s` in {new, updated, lost}). These documents have a field named `ip_s`. These documents also have a field `nlink_i` that can be equal to 0.

What I want to know is: how many new ip_s I have. Where I consider a new ip is an ip that belong to a document whose `state_s="new"` that does not appear in any document with `state_s = "updated"` OR `state_s = "lost"` .

Using Solr facet search I found a solution using the following query parameters:

- q=sate_s:"lost"+OR+sate_s:"updated"
- facet=true&facet.field=ip_s&facet.limit=-1

Basically, all ip in

```
"facet_fields":{
      "ip_s":[
        "105.25.12.114",1,
        "105.25.15.114",1,
        "114.28.65.76",0,
        ...]
```

with 0 occurence (e.g. 114.28.65.76) are "new ips".

Q1: Is there a better way to do this search. Because using the facet query describe above I still need to read the list of ip_s and count all ip with occurence = 0.

Q2: If I want to do the same search, (i.e. get the new ip) but I want to consider only documents where nlink_i>0 how can I do?. If I add a filter : `fq=nlink_i:[1 TO *]` all ip appearing in documents with link_i=0 will also have their number of occurrence set to 0. So I cannot not apply the solution describe above to get new ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution using facet.pivot that works for Q1 and Q2:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/query?q=nbLink_i:[1%20TO%20*]&updated&facet=true&facet.pivot=ip_s,state_s&facet.limit=-1&rows=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: To avoid the 0 count facets, you can use facet.mincount=1.

Q2: I think the solution above should also answer Q2?

Comment: I need the 0 ones, I only need them basically  if I could set facet.maxcount=0 I would but it does not exist.

Comment: I see - there is a Solr ticket about creating a facet.maxcount param; I don't see how you could get what you want without it via facetting. You could also look into inner queries; this link is relevant to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651759/solr-join-not-in-subselect

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to facets you can use [Solr grouping functionality](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing). The aggregation of values for your Q1 does not get much nicer, but at least Q2 works as well. It would look something like:

```
select?q=*:*&group=true&group.field=ip_s&group.sort=state_s asc&group.limit=1
```

In order for your programmatic aggregation logic to work, you would have to change your state_s value for new entries to something that appears first for ascending ordering. Then you would count all groups that contain a document with a "new-state-document" as first entry. The same logic still works if you add a fq parameter to address Q2.

Comment: That was a nice suggestion thank you. I haven't managed to get facet count inside groups. However grouping is nice especially if you need to get the id of the documents !

Comment: You don't need to use the facet count - instead you count groups.