# How to OR two joins in Solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have the following statement:

```
({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]) OR ({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z])
```

It doesn't return any documents, but if I use only one of the joins e.g.:

```
{!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
```

It returns some documents.

If I remove the date ranges it works as well:

```
({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_PM_Timerecord) OR ({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_CM_Request_Member)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? And what is wrong with the first statement?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In debug the parsed query looks like this:

```
(+JoinQuery({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_PM_Timerecord) +created:[1420074000000 TO 1451610000000]) (+JoinQuery({!join from=project_uuid to=id}type:EM_CM_Request_Member) +created:[1420074000000 TO 1451610000000])
```

And maybe I should mention that I use it as a filter query, but as far as i understand it that should not make a difference in the result.

Comment: What does debug tell you in the final parsed query?

Comment: I add the parsed query. It looks like it doesn't get parsed as I intended, but I still don't understand why.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch any thoughts?

Comment: I am stumped as well. May be worth asking this on the SolrUsers mailing list, perhaps you found a bug or there is something obvious others will notice. Just make sure to retest this on Solr 6.2 first.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked now in the SolrUsers mailing list as recommended and I got an answer.

The query has to be split up in multiple queries like this:

```
&q={!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$q1} OR {!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$q2} 
&q1=type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z] 
&q2=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
```

and it works fine.

My problem was that I put the whole thing under &q=... and apparently that was to much.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Need a way to specify the query of the `to` argument, and using query variables is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

On Solr 5/6 only the following was working on my side:

```
&fq=_query_:"{!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j1}" OR {!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j2} 
&j1=type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z] 
&j2=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
```

OR

```
&fq=_query_:"{!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j1}" {!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j2} 
&j1=type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z] 
&j2=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
```

I am not able to find any documentation about "_query_", i found the parameter on [Solr join "not in" subselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651759/solr-join-not-in-subselect)

You dont need the OR it will be ignored, but the joins are in OR.

Important: The first join have to be in _query_:"...join..."

More examples with negation:

```
&fq=-_query_:"{!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j1}" {!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j2} 
&j1=type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z] 
&j2=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]

&fq=_query_:"{!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j1}" {!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j2} -{!join from=project_uuid to=id v=$j3} 
&j1=type:EM_PM_Timerecord AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z] 
&j2=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
&j3=type:EM_CM_Request_Member AND created:[2015-01-01T01:00:00Z TO 2016-01-01T01:00:00Z]
```