# Solr nested join

Tags: solr, ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot-solr

```
select * from people
inner join submissions on people.id = submissions.person_id
inner join stage_transitions on submissions.id = stage_transitions.id
where stage_transitions.stage = 'lead'
```

I want to convert this sql query into solr query

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916297/how-to-or-two-joins-in-solr ? If this is something you're going to query for often (i.e. a common use case in your application) you might want to restructure your documents to be able to answer the query easier.

Comment: can i write that in adjust_solr_params or there is another way do fire that in rails, I am new to solr can you help me out, the URL you suggest is great, but I am not able to implement getting syntax error. Thank you