# Solr Facet for "related records"

Tags: solr, facet

I'm working on a Solr system that has parent/children items in the index:

```
id="id":"123456",
ss_type:"parent"
```

&

```
ss_parent_id=:"123456",
ss_type:"child"
```

How do I create a Facet showing Parent items that have children and Parent items that have no children?

I think this query gives me the results:

```
q={!join from=ss_parent_id to=id} *:*
```

But can I make that a facet that returns something like:

> With Children: 201
>
> Without Children: 109

If not, is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [use Facet queries](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.queryParameter) for this, as you can give the query parser there as well - in the same way as in your example.

```
facet.query={!join from=ss_parent_id to=id}*:*
```

The inverse might be harder, but [according to an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25453244/137650), there might be an option to prefix the query parser with  `-` (I didn't think this would work, so please try it out):

```
facet.query=*:* -({!join from=ss_parent_id to=id}*:*)
```

Comment: The negative does seem to work, thank you. One thing I don't really understand is how to get a facet.field to reflect the 2 queries.

Comment: The results are included under the `"facet_queries" : {` key in the result. The usual `facet.field` argument also supports `{!key="with_parent"}fieldname` the change the output key - the queries might do the same - try it!